# Массово получить категории товаров одним запросом WP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Задача собрать все категории и подкатегории имеющие отношение к позициям из массива товаров одним запросом средствами WP, гугл не помог.
На входе имею массив типа:

```
Array(
[0] => 27648,
[1] => 27649,
[2] => 27650,
[3] => 27651,
[4] => 27652,
[5] => 27653,
[6] => 27654,
[7] => 27655,
[8] => 27656,
[9] => 27657,
[10] => 27658,
[11] => 27659,
[12] => 27660,
[13] => 27661,
[14] => 27662,
[15] => 27663,
[16] => 27664,
[17] => 27665,
[18] => 27666,
[19] => 27667,
[20] => 27668,
)
```

На выходе массив с id / slag / guid / permalink / name / lable что можно вытянуть для категорий и подкатегорий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете получить все категории относящиеся к определенной записи через функцию [get_terms](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms)

```
// ваш массив с id товаров
$product_ids = [27648, 27649, 27650, 27651];

$products_categories = get_terms(
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'object_ids' => $product_ids,
    ]
);
```